# How do I skip MSN setup and launch IE directly on windows 98?

Tags: windows, windows-98

I've managed to install Windows 98 on a vm machine.

[image]

The internet connection works well for the vm.

[image]

However, each time I try to launch IE, some kind of MSN shows up, shown as the following screenshot, which ask me to select modem type.

[image]

How do I skip the MSN setup and launch IE directly?

Comment: I 'love' its single-minded determination. It's 1998, you **must** need to set up a modem before you can access the interwebz! I think I'd been on the interwebz about 6 years by then, by 98 on ISDN, over ethernet… ;)

Comment: Delete/save that MSN icon off your desktop. The standard connect me to the internet 3 option wizard should then pop up. You could also try to goto Internet Options in the control panel and click on connections tab, than the setup button, specifying that you want to connect manually.

Comment: `I've managed to install Windows 98` I'm sorry...

Comment: Download Chrome for Windows 98 . Search says you can still do this. Then use Chrome instead. That should work

Comment: You might get some more useful help if you ask this in [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: If your point is to have a browser.  At this specific period of time, Netscape was a far better browser.  You might be able to find a copy.  And I loved windows 98se @squillman .. there was nothing else like it at the time ;)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I may be a touch jaded ;)

Answer (score 3):

Go into the Control Panel, then Internet Options. In the connections tab click "Setup" which launches the connection setup dialog. From inside this wizard you can select the following options:

- I want to set up my internet connection manually (LAN) - Next
- I connect through a local area network (LAN) - Next
- Automatic detection of proxy server - Next
- Do you want to setup an email account - No, Next, Finish.